# Are questions posted here from a project support link treated differently than questions that end up here for some other reason?

Tags: support, product-support

I'm having problems with RestSharp. Basically, my code will not run on Windows 10 Version 1703 but the same code runs on 1709.  I have debugged everything I can think of and so after Googling and not finding an answer I'm ready to push the support link at RestSharp.

The support link points to SO - however a question of the form "This code works in my app when compiled and run on 1709 but not 1703" seems as one that would be quick to be closed if I were to ask say a similar Python related question.

To save myself the aggravation I am trying to understand if a question of this nature is considered valid.

Comment: Doesn't matter at all. Why would it? I don't think anyone is paying us to do their support... So I see no reason for it to be treated any differently.  Stack's goal of building a repository of knowledge doesn't change depending on how you land on the site.

Comment: @Patrice:  Like, I *get* it, but given that [RestSharp's own UI doesn't do ***jack***](http://restsharp.org/) to inform the person looking for help what to do, it's no surprise they fell flat with their attempt.  It's ***not*** in our best interests to just shoot 'em down like this.  Let's get someone from the CM team to reach out instead.

Comment: Long story short:  it's fine to ask questions like this, but two things should happen: you shouldn't treat it like it's a full-blown support forum (since we're not), and the site that sent you there should have people who actively monitor and curate the tag.  You didn't exactly do your part but I'm not going to hold it against you since you were *literally* thrown in the deep end here.

Comment: This is a typical agile development problem, pretty rough on Windows devs because they are not used to that.  Anybody that *could* help you has already updated and can't get a repro.  Agile spins the care-taking off the company to the devs and end-users.  Not a real problem, they *can* update.  And should.  If you want somebody else to relay that unpleasant message then a github issue can do that for you.

Comment: @Makoto I completely agree with you, but you *might* be jumping the gun here. It appears the OP is actually asking on Meta before asking on main ("To save myself the aggravation..."). So, good on you PyNEwbie!

Answer (score 5):

A tool/library, whatever, having a support link pointing here does not in any way affect the perception and reaction to a question.

All questions need to follow [a set of guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and fall into a certain set of [categories](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) regardless of how they were born. Asking:

> This code works in my app when compiled and run on 1709 but not 1703

is not really sufficient without, at least, the accompanying code that allows others to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Fair.  But how are you supposed to know the rules of the game if you're not told them in advance?  [Here's their link to what they call "get help"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/RestSharp).

Comment: @Makoto and they are at fault for simply placing a link and not providing additional information. Though that is indeed an issue, it isn't what was asked. As such, it didn't cross my mind to bring it up.

Comment: That issue begat the one you're replying to. It's not hard to see how the OP got here.

Comment: The tour page of course.